# When will you be in through? What is the meaning of this question?

Tags: meaning, phrases, questions

I could not figure out the meaning of this question. Could someone explain me briefly? This statement was in "answering audience questions" which is a presentation guide line.

Comment: As a native English speaker I don't know either. Unless they meant "though" and it is a typo.

Comment: Could you give the contest of the sentence?

Comment: ... or the context? ;)

Comment: It sounds like a phrase overheard wrongly which was originally, 'When will you be coming through?' which means stopping over, or passing through a particular place, but it's just a guess.

Comment: You have updated your question with a reference, but not enough detail to help us locate the actual context. Do you have access to the sentences the preceded and followed your sentence? Can you post them here?

Comment: Actually there are no preceded or followed by any sentence. The questioned was ordered as articles, but , here is the order : 1- who are you? 2 what are you going to talk about? and 3- When will you be through? (now ı start to meaning ı guess:)

Comment: _When will you be through_ is different than sentence that you posted in your question title. It makes sense, as explained in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Oopps :( I have just realised that misspelling in the post , thank you and thank u for effort:)

Comment: So are we done here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a typo.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence does not appear to stand on its own, so context would be required to provide a better answer. However, assuming there was a transmission error, we have a few possibilities:

> When will you be in Through?

Assuming that capitalization was forgotten, the asker may wish to know when you will arrive at a location called "Through."

> When will you be through?

Assuming that the *in* doesn't belong, the asker wants to know when you will be finished.

> When will you be in, though?

Assuming a misspelling and a dropped comma, the asker wants to know when you will arrive at your destination.

Comment: [Over the River and Through the Wood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over_the_River_and_Through_the_Wood).

Comment: very likely "When will you be through?" , especially since the opening poster wrote it this way in a comment.   Here, in terms of meaning, "through" can be replaced with "finished", as in "When will you be through with your lecture?"

Answer (score 1):

A possible meaning is that this question is asking for a period when the person will be "In" as opposed to "Out".  When discussing a movie's run a a theater you can say that "Movie X will run through the Week of March 9" or some such.

So the question could be asking what period of days or weeks this person will be "in"